# Кастомный select или css appearance

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, вёрстка

Нет ли проблем с кроссбраузерностью при изменении стилей нативного `select` с помощью appearance?

Сейчас делаю `select` с нуля(с помощью `divов, aria-атрибутов и рукописной js логики).

Но так как это несколько сложно + едва ли такой вариант можно использовать со сторонними библиотеками валидации форм, возникает вопрос: так уж плох appearance в кроссбраузерности и может не стоит выдумывать велосипед с кастомным `select`.

Может есть, те кто задавался таким вопросом, или у кого есть ответ на него?

Comment: если Вам только сам select стилизовать надо, то проблем нет. но option внутри Вы не сможете стилизовать никак. именно поэтому и приходится верстать с нуля с помощью дивов и js-логики

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: @EnKratia есть прикольная статья и решение в ней про `select`: https://web-standards.ru/articles/native-and-custom-select/